# How to combine multiple data frame date columns into one stacked date column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, multiple-columns, stacked

I have the following data frame, which records the names of individuals, their jobs, and how many hours they worked on a given day:

```
test_df <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark", "Stacy", "Anthony", "Colette"),
                      Job = c("Bartender", "Bartender", "Host", "Server"),
                      "01-Jan" = c(4, 5, 0, 6),
                      "03-Jan" = c(3, 7, 7, 8),
                      "04-Jan" = c(8, 0, 5, 4),
                      "07-Jan" = c(5, 6, 6, 7),
                      "08-Jan" = c(6, 8, 4, 0))
```

The above data frame only has one row corresponding to the name of each person, and then has a column for each day, which records how many hours a person worked in that particular day. I want to switch this, so that each person's name appears in 5 rows (corresponding to the 5 days represented in the data frame), and then there is "Date" column and an "Hours" column, showing how many hours a person worked and on what day, one row at a time. Like so:

```
test_df_2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark",
                               "Stacy", "Stacy", "Stacy", "Stacy", "Stacy",
                               "Anthony", "Anthony", "Anthony", "Anthony", "Anthony",
                               "Colette", "Colette", "Colette", "Colette", "Colette"),
                      Job = c("Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender",
                              "Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender", "Bartender",
                              "Host", "Host", "Host", "Host", "Host",
                              "Server", "Server", "Server", "Server", "Server"),
                      Date = c("01-01-2020", "01-03-2020", "01-04-2020", "01-07-2020", "01-08-2020",
                              "01-01-2020", "01-03-2020", "01-04-2020", "01-07-2020", "01-08-2020",
                              "01-01-2020", "01-03-2020", "01-04-2020", "01-07-2020", "01-08-2020",
                              "01-01-2020", "01-03-2020", "01-04-2020", "01-07-2020", "01-08-2020"),
                      Hours = c(4, 3, 8, 5, 6,
                               5, 7, 0, 6, 8,
                               0, 7, 5, 6, 4,
                               6, 8, 4, 7, 0))
```

I want to write a script in R to turn the first data frame into the second, but I'm unsure how. I've looked around at other stack overflow answers regarding combining multiple data frame columns into one, but I can't see how to get the rows to populate the right number of times, with the corresponding dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [tidyr::pivot_longer()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(test_df, 3:7, names_to="Date", values_to="Hours")
```

This will create the output structure you are looking for. You'll then only have to recode the values in the `Date` column.

Another option would be using the [reshape2::melt()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.4/topics/melt):

```
melt(test_df, id.vars=c("Name", "Job"), variable.name = "Date", value.name="Hours")
```

tidyr/pivot_longer appears to be the newer kid on the block, though.

[This article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/09/reshape-r-package-reshape2-melt-and-cast/) explains the concepts at work quite well.